# Insert record into db2 table using ASP and return result

Tags: asp-classic, db2

I'am trying to insert record into db2 table and getting a result with response.write.
My response is Insert OK, but the record isn't inserted in my table.  Here's the code I use:

```
<%
dim connection
dim sSQL, sConnString

sSQL="INSERT INTO db.tablename (LOGON,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR) VALUES ('logonTest','2012-    06-20-12.00.00.000000','blabla')" 

sConnString="data source=blabla;user id=jhonsonjack;password=mypassword"

Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

connection.Open(sConnString)

On Error Resume Next

connection.execute(sSQL)
if Err.number<>0 or connection.Errors.Count <> 0 Then
response.write "Insert Failed"
else
response.write "Insert OK"
end if
On Error Goto 0

Connection.Close
Set Connection = Nothing
%>
```

Any idea on what's wrong in it?

As an update, my insert is now almost working fine.  I say almost, cause i try to insert 4 records in my table, but this code only process the two firsts "insert into" and I don't understand why.

```
<%
dim connection
dim sSQL
dim sConnString

sSQL="INSERT INTO XXXXX.XXXXX(LOGON,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,ACCOUNT_TYPE,TO_DISABLE,APPLICATION_NAME,ACCOUNT_MODEL,DESCRIPTION,OWNER,FAC_SECURITY,CUPID,REG_FORM,CFIRM_DATE,TO_DELETE,DOCLINK) VALUES ('XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','0','XXXXX','4','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','0','XXXXX','','XXXXX');INSERT INTO XXXXX.XXXXX (LOGON,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,ACCOUNT_TYPE,TO_DISABLE,APPLICATION_NAME,ACCOUNT_MODEL,DESCRIPTION,OWNER,FAC_SECURITY,CUPID,REG_FORM,CFIRM_DATE,TO_DELETE,DOCLINK) VALUES ('XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','0','XXXXX','4','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','0','XXXXX','','XXXXX');INSERT INTO XXXXX.XXXXX (LOGON,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,ACCOUNT_TYPE,TO_DISABLE,APPLICATION_NAME,ACCOUNT_MODEL,DESCRIPTION,OWNER,FAC_SECURITY,CUPID,REG_FORM,CFIRM_DATE,TO_DELETE,DOCLINK) VALUES ('XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','0','XXXXX','4','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','0','XXXXX','','XXXXX');INSERT INTO XXXXX.XXXXX (LOGON,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,ACCOUNT_TYPE,TO_DISABLE,APPLICATION_NAME,ACCOUNT_MODEL,DESCRIPTION,OWNER,FAC_SECURITY,CUPID,REG_FORM,CFIRM_DATE,TO_DELETE,DOCLINK) VALUES ('XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','0','XXXXX','4','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','0','XXXXX','','XXXXX');"

sConnString="data source=XXXXX;user id=XXXXX;password=XXXXXXXXXX"

Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

connection.Open(sConnString)

set rs = connection.execute(sSQL)
if Err.number<>0 or connection.Errors.Count <> 0 Then
response.write "Insert Failed"
else
response.write "Insert OK" %><br><% response.write sSQL
end if
Connection.Close
%>
```

Any idea on what's wrong in there ?

Comment: Is that a typo, or is that malformed timestamp string what you're actually inserting (and I'm assuming you're inserting it into a timestamp, and not char/varchar, field).  Are you sure that it's connecting okay?  You do `On Error Resume Next` after opening the connection string, which means if opening that fails, your program won't notice.  Also, what about transaction - could this be the simple case where you just need to `COMMIT` the records?

Comment: It's effectively malformed. It should be '2012-06-20-12.00.00.000000'.  It should be connecting OK cause I  use the same settings as in the application itself, and it's working fine.  I try to make this script to add many records at a time in my DB

Comment: If it's malformed, then you should be getting an error (because the system goes "what the heck are you giving me?").  Besides just outputting "Insert OK", why not output more debug states - that might give more insight into your problem.  Also (and I've never messed with asp-classic) where does `On Error Goto 0` point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if any data is inserted into the table with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM FINALE TABLE
(INSERT INTO...)
```